# Pass props parameter to function in React.js when mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I am mapping through props in a components render method, can I pass in prop values to a function. I have forgotten the correct way to do this. For instance I have a category tag control which just lists some categories with a name, however onClick I want to perform some functionality for the individual category.

```
var React = require("react");

var CategoryTags = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    categories: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  },

  render: function() {

      var categoryRows = this.props.categories.map(function (c, i) {

        return (
            <button onClick={ this.linkToCategory.bind(name) } >
              {c.name}
            </button>
        );

      }.bind(this));

    return (
        <span>{categoryRows}</span>
    );

  },

  linkToCategory: function (c) {
    console.log(c);
  }

});
```

So in this example, while mapping though the categories, I want to pass in the name of the individual category so I can parse the link. Of course it would make sense for the object to have a link property but it didn't in this case.

Example of the categories object being passed in to the component props

`categories = [{'name': 'cat1'}, {'name': 'cat2'}];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding a function inside `.map` is not a good idea, because you are always going to pass a new function to the component, even if no other prop changed. That means it will always be re-rendered, even if it doesn't have to be.

But anyways, the problem with your code is that

1. There is no variable `name`.
2. You are using `.bind` incorrectly.

The call should be

```
this.linkToCategory.bind(this, c.name)
```

The first argument passed to bind `.bind` is the value of `this`, not the first argument (which you *should* know since you are using `.bind(this)` as well).

You can learn more about `.bind` in the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo in the .bind method I had it as `.bind(c.name)` but I forgot to pass in `this` as the first argument.

Comment: Is there any React documentation on how to avoid re-rendering when you need to call a function while mapping through props, or an alternative approach?

Comment: What I have done was to simply create another component which accepts a callback. E.g. you could have your own Button component, which accepts `name` and an `onClick` handler as prop, and which simply passes the `name` prop to the handler when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return a function from your event handler:

```
var CategoryTags = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    categories: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  },

  render: function() {

      var categoryRows = this.props.categories.map(function (c, i) {

        return (
            <button onClick={this.linkToCategory(c)} >
              {c.name}
            </button>
        );

      }.bind(this));

    return (
        <span>{categoryRows}</span>
    );

  },

  linkToCategory: function (c) {
      return () => {
          console.log(c);
      }
  }

});
```